# Convert CSV file to XLS file in Linux Environment (SSR 8020 Ericsson)

Tags: linux, excel, csv

I have CPU_status.csv file and I am trying to convert it to a CPU_test.xls format using following script "*./Test.sh*" in Linux VI (Ericsson SSR8020) but I am always getting one column in excel when I ftp out. Suggestion and feedback are appreciated. Thank guys.

[image]

```html
#!/bin/bash
echo "Check CPU"
tail -n +2 CPU_status.csv | head -1 | awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"}{print $1,$3,$16,$33,$50,$67,$81,$98}'| column -t;tail -n 50 CPU_status.csv | awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"}{print $1,$3,$16,$33,$50,$67,$81,$98}' | column -t
echo "Hit Enter to Continue..."
sleep 1
read continue

echo "./Test.sh>CPU_test.xls"
./Test.sh>CPU_test.xls
echo "Hit Enter to Continue..."
sleep 1
read continue
```

Answer (score 0):

You can produce semicolon delimited file and then excel reads the data in the way you need and spreads them into succeeding columns. Additionally remove `column -t` command.

It shoul look like this:

`tail -n +2 CPU_status.csv | head -1 | awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"; OFS=";"}{print $1,$3,$16,$33,$50,$67,$81,$98}'; tail -n 50 CPU_status.csv | awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"; OFS=";"}{print $1,$3,$16,$33,$50,$67,$81,$98}'`

Comment: Thank for reply. Sadly, this is not a solution that I am looking for. I know how to change these in MS Excel. I am looking more towards making tables and columns in Linux shell scripting without needing to edit in excel again and again everyday. Something like cronjob data.

Comment: ok, so modify you script section which produces the output file to be semicolon separated. I've edited the answer. Check it please

Answer (score 0):

Perl has handy CPAN modules for reading and writing Excel .xls and xlsx.

```
#!/home/utils/perl-5.8.8/bin/perl
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
use warnings;
use strict;
# open input file (fields delimited by ',')
my $inputfile = shift;
my $outputfile = shift;
open my $IN, '<', $inputfile, or die "Could not open $inputfile";
# Create a new Excel workbook
my $workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new($outputfile);
# Add a worksheet and a row
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
my $xlscol = my $xlsrow = 0;
for my $line (<$IN>) {
    print "\$line:  $line";
    my @fields = split /,/, $line;
    print "\@fields:  @fields\n";
    for my $csvcol (1, 3, 16, 33, 50, 67, 81, 98) {
        $xlscol++;
        print "$xlsrow\t$xlscol\t$csvcol\t$fields[$csvcol]\n";
        $worksheet->write($xlsrow, $xlscol, $fields[$csvcol]);
    }
    $xlsrow++;
}
# Usage:  writeXlsExample.pl CPU_status.csv my.xls
# File has been written to my.xls
```